# pandas groupby transform weighted average

Tags: python, pandas

I find a lot of examples online where the weighted average is computed for different groups, but all those tend to summarizse the data rather than transform them.

I would like to amend the below code to use the weighted mean, and weight by, say, `distance`

```py
import pandas as pd
from nycflights13 import flights
df = flights.query("air_time.notnull() and distance.notnull()", engine="python")
df.myvar =  df.groupby(['origin','day'])['air_time'].transform('mean')
```

Essentially I am looking for a way to use `transform`, instead of `join` and `apply` to get the same result as:

```
df = df.merge(df.groupby(['origin','day']).apply(lambda x: np.average(x.air_time, weights=x.distance)).reset_index(),
              on = ['origin','day'])
```

Comment: kindly create a small dataset, with expected output. You can also include what you tried

Comment: I added codes that produce the desired result...

Answer (score 0):

The next work for me. Just put the lambda function for weighted mean inside transform, for example in your case:

```
df.myvar =  df.groupby(['origin','day'])['air_time'].transform(lambda x: np.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, "distance"]))
```

or

```
wm = lambda x: np.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, "distance"])
df.myvar =  df.groupby(['origin','day'])['air_time'].transform(wm)
```

for better readability.